# Can't remove this string from an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Can't seem to get this right. What am I missing?

3 errors found:

> File: K:\CustomerLister2.java  [line: 16] Error: The method length()
>   is undefined for the type java.util.ArrayList File:
>
> K:\CustomerLister2.java  [line: 18] Error: The type of the expression
>   must be an array type but it resolved to
>
> java.util.ArrayList File: K:\CustomerLister2.java 
>   [line: 20] Error: The type of the expression must be an array type but
>   it resolved to java.util.ArrayList

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomerLister2 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();

        name.add("Chris");
        name.add("Lois");
        name.add("Meg");
        name.add("Meg");
        name.add("Brain");
        name.add("Peter");
        name.add("Stewie");

        for (int i = 0;  i < name.length(); i++) {
            if (name[i].equals("Meg")) {
                name[i] = null;
                break;
            }     
            for(String names: name) {
                System.out.println(names);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> The method length() is undefined for the type java.util.ArrayList

you want:

```
for ( int i = 0;  i < name.size(); i++){
```

> The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to java.util.ArrayList

you want:

```
name.get(i)
```

and

```
name.remove(i);
name.set(i,"");
```

---

or, you can just convert it into an array:

```
String[] nameArray = name.toArray(new String[0]);
```

and use `nameArray` instead of `name` (and `.legnth` instead of `.length()`).

Answer (score 2):

Use an `Iterator` if you want to remove items from an `ArrayList` otherwise a `ConcurrentModificationException` will occur when attempting to remove elements while iterating over the collection using an `for` loop

```
for (Iterator<String> iter = name.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    if (iter.next().equals("Meg")) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) javadoc.

```
String s = "Meg";
while(name.contains(s))
  name.remove(s);
```